# Creating multiple Pinot segments from CSV file (Apache Pinot data ingestion)

Tags: olap

I am trying to find information on how segmentation works on the data ingested using "bin/pinot-admin.sh LaunchDataIngestionJob -jobSpecFile ".

I have used the basic table configuration with no indexes defined and the segmentation section only has

"segmentsConfig" : {
"replication" : "2",
"schemaName" : "Customer"
}

When I use this command to upload data of size 7GB, it is creating only a single segment with 52 million rows.

Can any one help me in finding the configuration to specify the segmentation column? or any other configuration by which I can control the number of segments?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Number of segments is controlled by number of input files provided to the ingestion job. To create more multiple segments, you can split your input csv file into multiple parts and then run the ingestion job.
https://docs.pinot.apache.org/basics/getting-started/frequent-questions/operations-faq#how-to-control-number-of-segments-generated

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)